# ScrollView filling screen when child textview is too large

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with 3 children with weights to set their proportions: 1/7, 3/7, 3/7. The last section contains text that could extend outside the space allowed, so I added a scrollview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/package_status_border"/>

   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PackageContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is working fine if the PackageContent text is small:
[expected formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRFoA.png)

But, if the PackageContent text is large, rather than maintaining the expected height and just scrolling the extra text it is filling the entire screen:
[bad formatting, with scroll view filling entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX4io.png)

How to I make sure that the last section is still only 3/7 of the screen, with content scrolling, regardless of how much content the textView contains?

I have also tried putting the ScrollView within its own LinearLayout but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/package_status_border"/>

   <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3">

       <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/PackageContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       </ScrollView>

   </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, same problem using FrameLayout